# Returning result of a resolved promise from factory

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angularjs-factory

I have an Angular app, which contains a menu that is defined in av MVC view. So the menu is not related to the routes in the app. In the menu controller, I would like to inject an object containing data about the current user. I will then loop this object to decide which menu items should be visible to the user.

The factory looks like this:

```
.factory('currentUser', ['currentUserResource', function (currentUserResource) {return currentUserResource.get()}])
```

The get method is a standard $resource GET method.

Problem is, the factory returns a promise which takes a short while to resolve. So in my controller, some of the menu items are processed before the promise is resolved, and aren't showing when they should show.

In my controller I inject 'currentUser', and then have tried using in these ways:

```
$scope.currentUser = currentUser.then(function (data){
  return data
});

$scope.currentUser = currentUser;

currentUser.then(function(data){
  $scope.currentUser = data;
});
```

Is there any way, without using routing resolve, I can make sure that currentUser is resolved before the controller is loaded, or atleast that it is resolved first thing the controller does?

Comment: Does `currentUser` have a `$promise` property? If so try chaining off of that.

Comment: @georgeawg It does, but it doesn't seem to make a difference. It still takes a little while before the promise is resolved, and the controller carries on with the rest of the work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `$promise` property of the `$resource` object to delay the work of the controller.

```
resourceObject.$promise.then ( function onFulfilled(object) {
    //Do work that needs fulFilled object
}).catch (function onRejected(response) {
    console.log(response.status)
});;
```

If the the `resourceObject` has been resolved, the `onFulfilled` function will be execute immediately. If the `resourceObject` has not been resolved, the `$q` service will wait before invoking the `onFulfilled` function.

> It is important to realize that invoking a `$resource` object method immediately returns an empty reference (object or array depending on `isArray`). Once the data is returned from the server the existing reference is populated with the actual data.
>
> The Resource instances and collections have these additional properties:
>
> - `$promise`: the [promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) of the original server interaction that created this instance or collection.
>
>   On success, the promise is resolved with the same resource instance or collection object, updated with data from server. This makes it easy to use in resolve section of [$routeProvider.when()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) to defer view rendering until the resource(s) are loaded.
>
>   On failure, the promise is rejected with the [http response](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) object, without the resource property.

-- [AngularJS $resource Service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)